# How to get all pages of a notebook MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-onenote, microsoft-graph-api

Can i get all pages from a notebook using something like :

```
GET /sites/{id}/onenote/notebooks/{id}/pages
```

Currently, to get pages i use :

```
GET /sites/{id}/onenote/notebooks/{id}
GET /sites/{id}/onenote/notebooks/{id}/sectionGroups
GET /sites/{id}/onenote/sectionGroups/{id}/sections
GET /sites/{id}/onenote/sections/{id}/pages
```

Is there another way to get directly all pages from a notebook without using multiple GET !?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using batching to execute multiple GETs. You may still need multiple requests, but at least you can reduce the number of those. Looks like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
...
BODY
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/sites/{id}/onenote/sections/{id1}/pages"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/sites/{id}/onenote/sections/{id2}/pages"
    },
  ]
}
```

Here is the documentation on [microsoft graph request batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching)